# Can I control a Particle System seed with a driver in Blender 2.8?

Tags: particles, keyframes, drivers

I am creating a series of randomized scenes for a D&D Battle Map project. I would like to do as little effort as possible, naturally, so I am trying to generate a few instances of the same scene using different seeds from my particle system to avoid tiling.

Of course, I'd rather use a DRY method than simply keying a new value every frame, especially if I make this file a pipeline piece. My theory is that using a driver, I could say "Seed # = Frame #" and be done.

Unfortunately, I'm not seeing the option to attatch a driver to the ParticleSys seed parameter, even though other parameters like Hair Length do offer me that luxury.

I'm not sure if this is simply a missing feature or bug of 2.8. 2.79 does have this function, so I am seeing if this is possible there.

Edit: I have tried using 2.79 and simply keyframing the seed change to prove this even works, but it seems to just change the scale of the object rather than the position. If i scrub through seeds by hand, it does change the position but when I render it doesn't. This is what it is [currently doing](https://giphy.com/gifs/blender-d8FGt3mY1Qu2g8XPB9)

Edit: The scale changing is because I had enabled random scale changes under Render -> Object settings.

Comment: In the current particle system, you can't animate the seed of particles. When you change the seed it refreshes the particle cache.

Comment: That is really frustrating. Are there other ways to automatically iterate the seed of a system to mimic an animation? I just want it to spit out iterations of an object for me. Perhaps this is possible with a script?

Comment: With animation nodes, you can change the seed of particles forcefully BUT as I said it will refresh the cache. If you can make a simple example of your project with some screenshot then I can help you.

Comment: I will share an example shortly. What problems are caused by refreshing the cache in this situation?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rLIghC9 Example

Comment: It starts from the beginning. So if you refresh on each frame then the particles do not have time to simulate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92422/discussion-between-rug-and-3dsinghvfx).